# User home directory in apache pig scripts

Tags: apache-pig

How do I access user home directory value in Apache Pig?

I can, of course, do

```
pig -p HOME=$HOME
```

but I wonder if there is something pre-defined.

Use case:

```
register $HOME/mylibs/foo.jar
```

Comment: not sure how you are using the home directory, but you can run the shell command from inside the pig scripts, so you may access home directory using shell script as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an environment variable in your Pig script by declaring it at the beginning of your script.
E.g:

```
%declare HOME `echo $HOME`;
A = LOAD '$HOME/data' as (name:chararray, type:chararray);
B = foreach A generate name;
...
```